# Rows to Column based on common field in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I've a file1 contanining data like below.

```
ID,ADD1,ADD2
101,LDN,FRN
101,JPN,STZ
101,USA
102,LDN,FRN
102,JPN,STZ
103,JPN,STZ
103,USA
```

Desired output

```
ID, ADD1,ADD2,ADD3,ADD4,ADD5
101,LDN, FRN, JPN, STZ, USA
102,LDN, FRN, JPN, STZ
103,JPN, STZ, USA
```

It should find max(fields) for paricular ID and then randomly create the header first.
After that it should bring all values for each IDs and print in one row.

Thanks

Comment: And what happens if you try to program this?

Comment: I tried  perl -lp00e 's/\n/ /g' file1 and output comes in 1 row. ID,ADD1,ADD2 101,LDN,FRN 101,JPN,STZ 101,USA 102,LDN,FRN 102,JPN,STZ 103, JPN,STZ 103,USA.    No idea how to find max(ID) and generate dynamic headers. And after that how to create separate rows for each IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not worried about the output's sequence(means it should be same as Input_file) then following may help you on same:

```
awk -F, '
FNR==1{
  f=$0;
  sub(/.*[a-zA-Z]/,"",f);
  header=$0;
  next
}
{
  val=$1;
  $1="";
  sub(/^,/,"");
  a[val]=a[val]?a[val] OFS $0:$0
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    value=value?value ORS i OFS a[i]:i OFS a[i];
    num=split(a[i],b,",");
    len=len>num?len:num
};
  while(++f<=len){
    header=header OFS "ADD"f;
};
  print header RS value
}
' OFS=,   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
ID,ADD1,ADD2,ADD3,ADD4,ADD5
101,LDN,FRN,JPN,STZ,USA
102,LDN,FRN,JPN,STZ
103,JPN,STZ,USA
```

Comment: @Anand, np. You could also select any of the answer as correct one too, whichever you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

Another:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
NR>1 {
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)                         # iterate all fields
        a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]==""?"":OFS)$i        # catenate values to a hash
    c[$1]+=(i-2)                               # keep count of items in hashes
}
END {
    for(i in c)                                # find the max count
        if(c[i]>m)
            m=c[i]
    printf "%s","ID,"                          # output header
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
        printf "%s%s","ADD" ++j,(m==i?ORS:OFS)
    for(i in a)                                # iterate and output values
        print i,a[i]
}' file
ID,ADD1,ADD2,ADD3,ADD4,ADD5
101,LDN,FRN,JPN,STZ,USA
102,LDN,FRN,JPN,STZ
103,JPN,STZ,USA
```

**Edit**:

For the request in the comments, the `for` loop is unnecessary in the `NR>1{}` block and could be replaced with somewhat more straight forward code:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
NR>1 {
    id=$1; $1=""                               # store and reset $1
    a[id]=a[id] $0                             # catenate the whole $0 to hash
    c[id]+=(NF-1)                              # keep count of items in hash
} 
END {
    for(i in c)                                # find the max count
        if(c[i]>m)
            m=c[i]
    printf "%s","ID,"                          # output header
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
        printf "%s%s","ADD" ++j,(m==i?ORS:OFS)
    for(i in a)                                # iterate and output values
        print i a[i]
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what i was looking for. Both answers are working fine.

Comment: Is there any way to improve performance because its taking huge time for file having 10K records.

Comment: Wut? `time awk -f script.awk file` for 10k of your given records runs in 0.132 s real time. What's your data really like?

Comment: My bad, its running fine. Issue was due to huge special characters in the file. After removing all those characters it running in miliseconds.

Comment: I do have one speed-up for it, posting it now. Please let me know if it cut any milliseconds off.

Answer (score 1):

Or do it with just shell

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset -A ids valueCount   # make them arrays
IFS=,                       # input separator

# read input (list of values per ID)
while read -r id valueList ; do
    [[ $id == 'ID' ]] && continue           # ignore header
    for val in $valueList ; do              # for all values in the list
        ids[$id]+="${ids[$id]:+, }$val"     # add value to the list
        ((valueCount[$id]++));              # count values
        [[ ${valueCount[$id]} -ge $maxCol ]] && maxCol=${valueCount[$id]} # get max(valueCount)
    done
done < rowsToColumns.in

# print the collected list of values
print "ID" ,ADD{1..${maxCol}}
for id in ${!ids[@]} ; do
    print "$id, ${ids[$id]}"
done
```